# What is the significance of the electron's wavelength for Momentum and Energy Resolved Tunneling Spectroscopy (MERTS)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-induction, quantum-tunneling

The technique called **momentum and energy resolved tunneling spectroscopy** (MERTS) is based on quantum tunnelling, whereby an electron can traverse a barrier which has a thickness of less than 3nm, by simply appearing on the other side of it.

Is there any theory in which this effect is considered to be related to classical electromagnetic induction, whereby a current in Conductor A can be induced in Conductor B without physical contact between them?

Does quantum theory imply that the electron's waveform is passing through the barrier *without* interacting with the quantum waveforms of the particles in the barrier? Is the threshold limit of 1-3nm considered to be a consequence of the electron's waveform being too long (in its wavelength) to form a standing wave in conjunction with the quantum waveform of the barrier material at that length scale, given that the formation of a standing wave would presumably negate forwards propogation of the intruding waveform?

In essence, what I'm interested in is whether the *wavelength* of the electron is considered to be the critical factor in the quantum tunnelling effect.

Answer (score 0):

A light wave passing through material goes beyond heat penetrated material and suggests a gamma energy light formed wavelength directed through, for example lead lining a box penetrated by a light wave from the inside radioactive object filled with energy and light.